# How to do aggregate on many-to-many relations in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm following http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Of course, with difference case.

How to do aggregate on roles table? Eq. maximum count user with roles Admin, minimun count users with roles admin, and average count users ?

Comment: Linked relations are not polymorphic. Anyway you want something like whereHas, which is there too http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Answer (score 0):

For any relations you can use this:

```
User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
  $query->where('name','=','admin');
})->count();
```

No point in getting avg, min or max in this very example.